# Add Break Points in .js file and .html file inside eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, breakpoints

Any One please tell me that `can i put break point in .js file or in .html file inside the eclipse`? I can put break points only in .java file. Have to add any plugins for that ah?

Note: I'm running the application in device, so if html file loaded with webview, then i want to debug that html file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for debugging javascript you could use firebug or if IE developer tools (F10) and put a breakpoint in the code as it runs on the client browser.

Comment: Thank you for your response. See, I'm running the application in device, so if html file loaded with webview, then i want to debug that html file

Answer (score 0):

Try jsHybugger: http://www.jshybugger.org/

It lets you set breakpoints, singlestep, catch exceptions, and interact with the JS/DOM environment. You can use it from Eclipse or from a Chrome or Chrome-compatible debugger on the remote desktop. It can be used with apps that create their own webView.

However, you have to install a few files -- but probably no more complicated to use than weinre. it does extensively modify the JS files (on the fly, transparently to the user) to enable all this debugging -- webKit really should support javascript debugging natively.